# Simple IF statement in XSLT two remove one element if found

Tags: xml, xslt

I transform some different structures of XML files at once using XSLT.

Some of them have a `<link></link>` element tag in their structure, and the others have either one of `<feedburner:origLink></feedburner:origLink>` and `<link></link>`, or both.

My question is how do I delete the `<feedburner:origLink></feedburner:origLink>` when is found with the `<link></link>` tag ?

This is what I use for now and some of the XMLs have two times a `<url></url>` element tag.

```
<xsl:template match="feedburner:origLink | link">
  <url>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </url>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you might be able to use a solution along the lines of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(link, feedburner:origLink)[1]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to match the element with a predicate specifying that the other one isn't there:

```
<xsl:template match="feedburner:origLink[not(../link)] | link">
  <url>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </url>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I just tested it. There still two <l> elements but also there are some elements who have the <feedburner:origLink> element.

Comment: You have the benefit of knowing what your source document looks like. The rest of us can only guess. You can't expect code written by someone who hasn't seen the XML document to actually work.

Comment: @MichaelKay This is my XML http://codepad.org/AaQk4dqU a standard feedburner feed